# Java - Update query does not work everytime

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, xampp, netbeans-8

This query worked at the start but when I updated it again and again it stopped working. I'am working on netbeans and using xampp server.
And one weird thing, now when the value is getting updated the last 2 rows and last column remain unchanged.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    String val = txt_val.getText();
    String col = txt_col.getText();
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/net", "root", "");

        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(
        "update userdetail set 
            name =  ?
        , username =  ? where  name =  ? AND  username =  ? ")

        pstmt.setString(1, val);
        pstmt.setString(2, val);

        pstmt.setString(3, col);
        pstmt.setString(4, col);

        int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if (i > 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "done");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "query failed");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> This query worked at the start but when I updated it again and again
>   it stopped working

This is logic, the problem is in your query :

**Problem**

```
update userdetail set name = ?, username = ? where name = ? AND username = ?
```

Suppose if your `name = "name" and username = "username`" in database
The new values `name = "name1" and username = "username1"`

**First update**

```
.. set name = "name1", username = "username1" where name = "name" AND username = "username"
```

**Second update**

If you repeat it again you will repeat your query with the old values of name and username:

```
.. set name = "name2", username = "username2" where name = "name" AND username = "username"
```

The name and username are changes in the first time, and there are no value in database like this : `name = "name" AND username = "username"`

---

**Solution**

Before your update you have to get the information from your database so you can update your record without any problem.

**Or**

The best practice is to update your record with a primary key that not changes, for example :

```
update ... where id = something
```

Hope you get my point.

Comment: I have not used any primary key in my table because I need to update the entire table if a name matches to it. For example if in the entire table there exists a name 'joey' I would replace it with 'x'

Comment: yes, so when you replace it the first time you cant replace it the second time, because its already changed @SnehaP right?

Comment: Right...so i'll have to use different parameters for comparison?

Comment: no, why you want to update again if your records already updated why you want to update them again? @SnehaP

Comment: I understood your explanation.But the code is still not running when I tried it on different table. Apart from that does anything else look wrong in the code?

Comment: what did you mean i really don't get you @SnehaP ?

Comment: @SnehaP can you tell me what you want to do, maybe i can suggest something better

Comment: considering there is a table with column named A,B,C and in the table cells there would be values 1,2,3 or NULL .I want to replace all the 1s with ONE 2S with TWO and so on.

Comment: yes it is .But its not working now the query must be wrong